# verify logical equivalence without truth table

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$(p\land q)\rightarrow r$ and $(p\rightarrow r)\lor (q\rightarrow r)$

Have to try prove if they are logically equivalent or not using the laws listed below and also if need to use negation and implication laws. I was going to use associative law and then distributive but I wasn't sure how to get rid of the "implies"

```
Commutative laws: p ∧ q ≡ q ∧ p
p ∨ q ≡ q ∨ p

De Morgan’s laws: ∼(p ∧ q) ≡ ∼p ∨ ∼q
∼(p ∨ q) ≡ ∼p ∧ ∼q

Idempotent laws: p ∧ p ≡ p
p ∨ p ≡ p

Associative laws: (p ∧ q) ∧ r ≡ p ∧ (q ∧ r)
(p ∨ q) ∨ r ≡ p ∨ (q ∨ r)

Distributive laws: p ∧ (q ∨ r) ≡ (p ∧ q) ∨ (p ∧ r)
p ∨ (q ∧ r) ≡ (p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∨ r)
```

Comment: Those two statements are not equivalent!  Did you maybe mean $(p \rightarrow r) \lor (q \rightarrow r)$?

Comment: how would i prove they are not equivalent ?

Comment: Im trying to prove if they are equivalent or not

Comment: Use a counterexample. I showed one in my Answer

Comment: Since there are no laws relating to implication, presumably implication is a derived concept, i.e. defined as a composition of the other connectives, e.g. $(p\to q)\equiv \neg(p\land\neg q)$.

Comment: Please take a minute to have a look at [how to format mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on Math SE, it will make things much easier to read, which is considered a mark of respect towards all readers of your posts. I also suggest 
that you bookmark this [very useful MathJax link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
for quick reference.

Comment: @Phyllotactic Good advice! Always looking to improve the community! Thanks! :)

Comment: @Phyllotactic Best wishes to you!! Keep up those logic skills! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the laws that you provide, you will not be able to prove their equivalence. You need an equivalence involving implications. Here is the one that is typically used:

Implication: $p \to q \equiv \neg p \lor q$

Use it as follows:

$$
\begin{align*}
(p \land q) \to r &\equiv \neg (p \land q) \lor r &(\text{Implication}) \\
&\equiv (\neg p \lor \neg q) \lor r &(\text{De Morgan}) \\
&\equiv (\neg p \lor \neg q) \lor (r \lor r) &(\text{Idempotence}) \\
&\equiv \neg p \lor (\neg q \lor (r \lor r)) &(\text{Association}) \\
&\equiv \neg p \lor ((\neg q \lor r) \lor r) &(\text{Association}) \\
&\equiv \neg p \lor (r \lor (\neg q \lor r)) &(\text{Commutation}) \\
&\equiv (\neg p \lor r) \lor (\neg q \lor r) &(\text{Association}) \\
&\equiv (p \to r) \lor (q \to r) &(\text{Implication})
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The two statements are not equivalent.

Obviously you cannot use equivalence principles to demonstrate non-equivalence, so let's use a counterexample:

Let $p=True$, $q =False$, and $r=False$

then $(p \land q) \rightarrow r = (T\land F) \rightarrow F = F \rightarrow F = T$

But $(p \rightarrow r) \land (q \rightarrow r) = (T \rightarrow F) \land (F \rightarrow F) = F\land T =F$

Comment: Sorry the RHS equation should be (p implies r) or ( q implies r )

Comment: Would that change the answer?

Comment: @M.Jones Ah! As I expected! Yes, that changes things, as now they *are* equivalent!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a equivalence:

```
1. p → q ≡ ¬p v q
```

I find it easier to work on the right side:

```
 (p ∧ q)→r ≡ (p → r) ∨ (q → r)
```

Taking only the right side:

```
(p → r) ∨ (q → r)   (Using 1.)

(¬p v r) ∨ (¬q v r) (Commutative laws on the right parentheses)

(¬p v r) ∨ (r v ¬q) (Associative laws)

¬p v ((r ∨ r) v ¬q) (Idempotent laws)

¬p v ((r) v ¬q)     (Commutative laws)

¬p v (¬q v r)       (Associative laws)

((¬p v ¬q) v r)     (De Morgan's laws)

¬(p ∧ q) v r        (Using 1.)

(p ∧ q) → r
```

Comment: [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) is a reference for mathjax to help typesetting maths on the site.